Angular 17: Primeng table is showing twice after provideClientHydration()
I am using angular 17 with provideClientHydration() if I disable the hydration my table is coming as expected but when I enable hydration, prime ng table rows are shown twice (duplicate rows below each other)
provideClientHydration(withHttpTransferCacheOptions({includePostRequests: true}))
below is table
<p-table #dt [value]="tokenList" dataKey="tokenId" [showFirstLastIcon]="false" [alwaysShowPaginator]="false" styleClass="p-datatable-striped" [paginator]="true" [rows]="30" [totalRecords]="totalRecord" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadMoreRecords($event)"[lazyLoadOnInit]="false" stateStorage="session" stateKey="token-table-session">
angular : 17.3.8
I tried to disable the provideClientHydration it's working but not when enabled
I tried with a lower version of angular but they still issue persist
